# Visual Studio seems to be throwing an error even when changing the code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

This is a really weird one and kinda difficult to explain, so stay with me.

I had some pretty basic c# code which runs based on an inputted string, then that string is used put into a logger and then it does some searches etc with it.. details are somewhat unimportant.

So, it keeps throwing a "Index was outside the bounds of the array." error even though for testing purposes I am manually setting the string array right before it uses it.

```
args[0] = "{XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}";
logger.Info("guid:" + args[0]); //Errors here
 _fetchxml = _myApp.getFetchXml("fileguid", args[0], new Guid(), new Guid());
```

I even just tried putting a line before the logger which just said `var a = "a"`, and it gave the same error on that line, which makes me think its something with the build?

[image]

I have cleaned and rebuild the solution but with no luck, hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: What happens if you put `Debug.WriteLine(args.Length);` before those lines of code?

Comment: It throws that same error exception, but on the `Debug.WriteLine` line

Comment: And there was no debug output? If so, then the exception is being thrown from somewhere else entirely.

Comment: Is logger an object of a custom class you wrote ? If so add a try catch inside the Info method and see if the exception is actually thrown inside of logger.

Comment: Sorry, but how `args[]` has been declared and initiated? Are you talking about `args` to `Main` function? Have you tried to use: `if(args == null || args.Length == 0)`?

Comment: @SmallerMe, can you possibly provide a completed code example?  Also, It will be better for us to reproduce your problem if you tell me what is your current project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array is immutable (i.e. fixed size), so if the Length of the array is zero, it will throw an exception if you try to add a string and assign it to its first position (which is non-existent).

As suggested in the comments, you can simply confirm if indeed args.Length is 0 by adding an if-block:

```
if(args.Length > 0)
{
    args[0] = "{XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}";
    logger.Info("guid:" + args[0]); //No more Errors here?
    _fetchxml = _myApp.getFetchXml("fileguid", args[0], new Guid(), new Guid());
}
else 
{ 
    logger.Info("guid: --no arguments found--"); 
    // or if _fetchxml is crucial:
    throw new ArgumentException("No guid given");
}
```

Or alternatively, if it's only for testing, you could replace the args array entirely:

```
args = new[] { "{XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}" };
```

Or better yet, set the argument in the debug section of the project properties under 'Start options' in 'Command line arguments' (assuming these are indeed command line arguments of course).